# SonarQube: ERROR a branch analysis cannot have the pull request analysis parameter 'sonar.pullrequest.key'

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running sonar-scanner with help of sonarqube.yml this code code snippet from there

```
  - name: Run sonarqube
    run: sonar-scanner
      -Dsonar.scm.provider=git
      -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONARQUBE_TOKEN }}
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{ github.event.number }}
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF#refs/heads/}
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${GITHUB_BASE_REF#refs/heads/}
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}
      -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.endpoint=${GITHUB_API_URL}
```

Error after creating merge request
[image]

1. SonarQube Scanner version 4.2.0.1873
2. SonarQube server version 9.0.1

i see in executing log that is remaining -Dsonar.pullrequest.key= to be equal to undefined

```
Run sonar-scanner -Dsonar.scm.provider=git -Dsonar.login=***  -Dsonar.pullrequest.key= -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF#refs/heads/} -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${GITHUB_BASE_REF#refs/heads/} -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.endpoint=${GITHUB_API_URL}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After merging branch to master it is commit and in that case ${{ github.event.number }} it's evaluating to null and it occures error so i suggest you to use in this case ${{github.sha}} even you can have condition

```
"-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=`if [ -z "${{github.event.number}}"  ]; then echo ${{github.sha}}; else echo ${{github.event.number}}; fi`"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? - 

```"-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=`if [ -z "${{github.event.number}}"  ]; then echo ${{github.event.number}}; else echo ${{github.sha}}; fi`"```

Comment: @RevanthKausikan `-z` means null (empty) string. So the code in the answer is saying if `.number` is empty then use the `.sha` else use `.number`. So the answer is correct.